# Want to redirect on Jquery tabs on click of Submit button

Tags: php, jquery

I want  a tutorial in which when I click on any submit button,i want to redirect on jquery tabs.
Like 
Tab1
Tab 2
Tab 3
Suppose I am at Tab1- When I click on Submit button,I want to move on Tab 2 and the like..

Please give me the solution of this?

Comment: Not until you post what you've tried so far. SO isn't about doing your work or assignments for you.

Comment: We usually deal with coding issues and not looking for library but now that I've used something similar, here's a plugin you can use -> http://mstratman.github.io/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/

Answer (score 2):

JS Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/smegha11/2kD3K/1/
when user click on the button you can use jquery tabs(); function and pass selected tab in it

```
 $('divSelector').tabs('select', index);
```

Html

```
 <div id="tabs">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Content for Tab 1</p><br/>
    <input type ="button" id="tab1btn" value = "Go to next tab">
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#tab1btn").click(function(){
   $('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);

});
```

});

Comment: I have tried the above solutions on my local host its not working.So will you please provide me a complete zip file of this.Means just a (DEMO).

Comment: ok please send me the email id

Comment: adnankhan.m@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

// get all tabs

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
```

Then using below syntax you can set default selected tab to any tabs you wish to

Suppose i have three tabs , then on submit i want to set 2nd tab as selected tab , as tab index starts from 0

```
$tabs.tabs('url', 1, "you full base url of second tab").tabs('select',1);
```

Comment: I tried both the codes.They are not working.